# Wamp and Wordpress on local host not loading Styles.css

Tags: css, wordpress, wamp

I have a site that is working perfectly online, but when i "migrate" it to localhost, using Wamp, it doesn't load the stylesheets.

I have looked to see if the styles are enqueued in the function.php file and it seems to be correct.

I have looked at my browser and inspected the site and I found that the styles are not being loaded on my site, on localhost, which means my CSS folder doesn't appear.

The online site works like a charm and loads everything like expected.

Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Well, this question has nothing to do with `css` can you please remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path of your CSS folder and path.

You can check the path is correct or not using two ways.

1 - Go with the view source and check what path is currently displayed in CSS.

2 - Go to console and check error there was a 404 error if the path is wrong.

Use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function to get proper child theme path.

Comment: Thanks, @Maulik I have tried but got the same error. It is for sure the way I m getting my CSS files and JS files because I find the problem in all this files. I m using WAMP to make my localhost and instead of going to my site using localhost/mysite i use something like http://dev.mysite.com:81. In my config.php I have the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() point to /commonfiles/js/script.js and /commonfiles/css/styles.css

Comment: @pedrodavim Then please check Site and Home URL and I believe that there Is an only problem with the path, try get_template_directory_uri() and checked that because it does not matter if you are in localhost or live server wp function always run. please check that and let me know if need more help.